# CUrl (MSVS Library) or libcurl?

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

CUrl is a default included class in MSVS10 under atlutil.h, while libcurl (cURL) is a third party opensource library for C (can also use the wrapper library cURLpp for C++).

I just wanted to know the main difference between the two and why the opensource cURL is used majorly over the default included library in MSVS10?

I do mean besides the fact that cURL (open source version) can be used on all platforms and compilers and utilises C rather than C++ (thus can be used in both cases).

There seems to be little talk about the Microsoft version other than the documentation on MSDN. Even people trying to use libcurl with c++ on MSVS10 don't seem to look at Microsoft equivalent. More restrictive functions and less power?

I am currently looking to create a C or C++ application that can look through the source of a webpage to go through its links (search engines) among a few other things - person project.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are almost entirely unrelated. ATL's `CUrl` is nothing more than a string manipulation utility - a bunch of helper methods to break a URL string into its component parts. It doesn't perform any network activity whatsoever.

libcurl is a library that implements a number of networking protocols. An equivalent Microsoft-provided technology would be [WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385331.aspx) and, to some extent, [WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384273.aspx)